# Android Camera Intent Rotation Issue

Tags: android, android-glide, android-camera-intent

I'm loading the camera as an intent and saving to a local file:

```
Intent capturePhotoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

capturePhotoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriPhoto);

startActivityForResult(capturePhotoIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
```

Some mobile phones are saving the image in the incorrect orientation. Where a photo is captured with the mobile phone held in portrait, the saved image is rotated 90 degrees to landscape.

Most phone cameras are landscape, therefore I understand this is why the rotation occurs. The camera application should populate the image file with the correct orientation within the EXIF data.

I understand that I could use Glide to display the captured image within the application and this will automatically handle the rotation for me.

```
Glide.with(myContext).load(photoFilePaths.get(iPosition)).into(myViewHolder.getPhotoImageView());
```

However, I believe that this rotates the image in the ImageView each time it is loaded - could Glide be used to rotate and save the image within the correct orientation onActivityResult?

I've seen the following could be an alternative, however this relies on the correct orientation being set within the EXIF data:

```
ExifInterface ei = new ExifInterface(photoPath);
int orientation  = ei.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED);

Bitmap rotatedBitmap = null;
switch(orientation) 
{
    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
        rotatedBitmap = rotateImage(bitmap, 90);
        break;

    ...
}

public static Bitmap rotateImage(Bitmap source, float angle) 
{
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(angle);
    return Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, 0, source.getWidth(), source.getHeight(), matrix, true);
}
```

Glide appears to be more consistent at displaying an image in the correct orientation, so I'm guessing it follows a different approach that could provide better results when saving the image. The image needs to be uploaded to a web server in the correct orientation, rather than just displaying within the Android application.

Comment: If you create a bitmap from a jpg file you should consider the orientation that is mentioned in the file and rotate the bitmap accordingly if needed. You can never say that the orientation is wrong as that is as it goes with jpg files.

Comment: Further: if you want to upload a file then upload the file. You do not need to use an intermediate bitmap to do so.

Comment: The orientation against the jpg file (Exif data) is dependent on the camera application implementing this correctly? Not all camera applications will set this data?

My application works offline, therefore the image is displayed (bitmap) within the application until the user connects to the server and uploads their captured data.

Comment: Repeat: if you create a bitmap from a jpg file you should consider the orientation that is mentioned in the file and rotate the bitmap accordingly if needed.